# Where are the R packages from previously installed versions?

Tags: r

After upgrading to `R` 3.6.2 I am getting a series of errors about earlier versions of libraries being used :

> Error: package ‘stringi’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
>   Execution halted

I have worked through several of these via

```
install.packages('stringi')
```

but that just leads down the rabbit hole to the next mismatched library.  What I'd like to do is en-masse upgrade the existing libraries. Here is a suggestion to use:

```
lib_loc <- "<old R library path"
to_install <- unname(installed.packages(lib.loc = lib_loc)[, "Package"])
to_install
install.packages(pkgs = to_install)
```

However - *where* is the `<old R library path>` on ubuntu?

**Update**  Based on suggestion from @RuiBarradas I ran:

```
 update.packages(ask=FALSE)
```

But the "different internals" errors shown above still happens for many packages. So I am still looking for an answer to how to upgrade the ones installed on the older version of R (3.4.4)

Comment: Are you looking for `?update.packages`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas  probably!  looking at that now

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I ran `update.package(ask=FALSE)` but the "different internals" error shown in the question still occurs for many packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following did the trick - thanks to @RuiBarradas for the pointer to `update.packages`:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said in my comment to use `checkBuilt = TRUE`, like I always use. Wasted your time looking for it.